# Save Form Properties in File and then restore those Properties after reopening

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I am currently an apprentice and pretty new to Delphi, so I apologize if there is something obvious I'm missing. And I have to note I have to work with a 22 years old legacy code with approx 600k lines so that could be an error factor as well :D

I was tasked to code a way to save all currently open Forms with their properties like size, position, and window state and then restoring it after reopening the program. For that I decided to add in the FormCloseQuery in the Main Form a procedure which goes through all forms and writes their data (if Visible true) in a .ini file. Works pretty great so far and this is how it looks like:

```
procedure SaveFormInformation();
var
  i : Integer;
  form : TForm;
  iniFile : TIniFile;
begin
  iniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'FormInfo.ini');
  try
    for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
    begin
      form := Screen.Forms[i];
      if form.Visible then
      begin
        iniFile.WriteInteger(form.Name, 'Width', form.Width);
        iniFile.WriteInteger(form.Name, 'Height', form.Height);
        iniFile.WriteInteger(form.Name, 'Left', form.Left);
        iniFile.WriteInteger(form.Name, 'Top', form.Top);
        iniFile.WriteBool(form.Name, 'Visible', form.Visible);
        iniFile.WriteBool(form.Name, 'IsMaximized', form.WindowState = wsMaximized)
      end;
    end;
  finally
    iniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And in the end, the .ini File it looks like this:

```
[F_Main]
Width=719
Height=542
Left=600
Top=305
Visible=1
IsMaximized=0
[F_PartList]
Width=1126
Height=716
Left=71
Top=301
Visible=1
IsMaximized=0
```

Now to my problem... the restoring.
At first, I tried the same way with Screen.FormCount and, if Visible, read the .ini file and replace the values. That only worked partially because we have so many forms (masks), we decided to not initialize some forms in the beginning because of performance.

Then I decided to turn things around and include a loop which reads the .ini and only changes what's written there. But before it changes the properties, it looks if the form exists in the first place and creates it when not there. This part does not work the way i intend it to. The if statement - lookup works:

```
if Application.FindComponent(Sections[i]) as TForm = nil then
```

But the Application.CreateForm() doesn't. It seems like it cannot find the classes with their respective names alone. Thankfully we have a naming convention here so every TForm starts with F_ and every TFormClass with TF_ so it should theoretically be possible.

Here is the procedure of RestoreForms():

```
procedure RestoreForms();
var
  i : Integer;
  iniFile : TIniFile;
  form : TForm;
  FormClass : TFormClass;
  Sections : TStringList;
begin
  iniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'FormInfo.ini');
  Sections := TStringList.Create;

  try
    IniFile.ReadSections(Sections);
    for i := 0 to Sections.Count -1 do
    begin

      {form := Application.FindComponent(Sections[i]) as TForm;
      if not Assigned(form) then
      begin
        FormClass := TFormClass(GetClass('T' + Sections[i]));
        Application.CreateForm(FormClass, form);
        form.Free;
      end;}

      //Since not all Forms are initialized in the beginning this bit
      //does it for you. If the Form is nil then create Form
      if Application.FindComponent(Sections[i]) as TForm = nil then
      begin
        //FormClass := TFormClass(FindClass('T' + Sections[i]));
        FormClass := TFormClass(GetClass('T' + Sections[i]));
        form := Application.FindComponent(Sections[i]) as TForm;
        Application.CreateForm(FormClass, form);
        form.Free;
      end;

      //this puts the current read form of the ini File in a TForm Object
      //to then change its properties
      form := Application.FindComponent(Sections[i]) as TForm;
      with form do
      begin
        form.Top := IniFile.ReadInteger(form.Name, 'Top', Top);
        form.Left := IniFile.ReadInteger(form.Name, 'Left', Left);
        form.Height := IniFile.ReadInteger(form.Name, 'Height', Height);
        form.Width := IniFile.ReadInteger(form.Name, 'Width', Width);
        if iniFile.ReadBool(form.Name, 'IsMaximized', WindowState = wsMaximized) then
          form.WindowState := wsMaximized
        else
          form.WindowState := wsNormal;
        form.Position := poDesigned;
        if not (Sections[i] = 'F_Main') then
          form.Visible := IniFile.ReadBool(form.Name, 'Visible', Visible);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Sections.Free;
    form.Free;
    iniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Currently, the code "opens" the program but no Form will be seen. Only Services in Task manager can free me of the process ^^"

I also thought about saving their Window States of all open Forms in their respective FormClass itself, but since we have like 1k forms, it makes this task close to impossible.

I hope you guys can give me some pointers or ideas since neither google nor Stack Overflow nor AI could give me any answers as of now.

Comment: Most stuff you seek is included in the JEDI component lib

Comment: You may get more useful replies when you tell us the Delphi version you are using.

Comment: I added the Delphi Version to the Question. Thank you for the info!

Comment: One approach is to create a routine or method that will open the ini file if it's not already open, and read the details of the _one_ form that is passed in a parameter to it, and set the values for that form.  Then in each form, overload the `Loaded` method and have it call this routine/method (passing itself).  In this way, each form effectively loads its own settings if and when it is opened.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment in the end i would have to change every existing Form with a method, in which the form pulls its own settings. But with around a thousand forms i would work on that till forever. And i want the non-Main Forms to be automatically opened after starting the Main Form. So if i'd have Form F_Main F_A and F_B open and close F_Main, all the info gets saved. Upon opening F_Main F_A and F_B should be initialized and opened with their settings before closing.

Comment: @Kanubbel, you'd have to change every form with an identical, essentially-one-liner, method in every case, but yes, 1000 forms is a lot even for that.

Comment: @Kanubbel Create a new base Form class with the necessary feature, and then update the existing Forms to derive from this new base class. Also, when closing the MainForm, store which Forms are still open in the INI so that on the next run you know which Forms to reopen

Comment: Likewise you may not want to treat every Form the same way - some of them may be dialogs with the buttons "_Ok_" and "_Cancel_" - in the latter case you might **not** want to save anything upon closing. And with "_Apply_" you may want to save settings while the window=Form remains open (instead of closing it/only saving on closing).

Comment: I cannot look closer at the moment to see if there are other issues, but you should not call form.free anywhere in that code. This will free the form that was already created and that is the reason you don't see any forms. When you create forms with `Application.CreateForm(FormClass, form)` application instance will be owner of those forms and will be responsible for their release when required.